# equals Test into sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to use equals into select is it possible to do it?

SELECT EXAMPLE

```
DECLARE @NAME_SURNAME varchar(200);
SELECT
(CASE WHEN (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME) != @NAME_SURNAME THEN (SET @NAME_SURNAME = (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME))  END) AS 'LP.',
```

Problem:

```
(SET @NAME_SURNAME = (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME))
```

Comment: Why do you need the CASE? If @NAME_SURNAME does not equal PLP.NAME + ' ' + PLP.SURNAME, you set it to this value? Seems superfluous.

Comment: DECLATE is DECLARE in your code, right?

Comment: @Cube32 this was only example. Now I fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL doesn't quite makes sense.  You seem to be trying to set a variable and return a value (as "LP.") at the same time.  This is not allowed.  Here is the note in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> A SELECT statement that contains a variable assignment cannot be used
>   to also perform typical result set retrieval operations.

The correct syntax for setting a variable using a `select` is this:

```
select @NAME_SURNAME = (CASE WHEN (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME) !=  @NAME_SURNAME
                             THEN (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME)
                             else @NAME_SURNAME
                        end)
```

That is, the `set` keyword is not allowed within a `select` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the word `SET` in this statement.

```
(@NAME_SURNAME = (PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @NAME_SURNAME = 
    CASE WHEN PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME != @NAME_SURNAME 
    THEN PLP.NAME +' '+ PLP.SURNAME
    ELSE @NAME_SURNAME
    END AS 'LP.'
```

But wouldn't this always select the same?